# Freelancer Game - where is the Area51 jumpgate

Tags: freelancer

I am playing freelancer (by Microsoft). it's a really old game, and I've downloaded the area 51 mod for it because I remember making huge $$ with it. I thought the jumpgate was in the debris field behind Pittsburg, but I can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it: It's behind manhattan.